# Table-like alignment of different-width columns with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Can this table behaviour be achieved using flexboxes or other CSS techniques? I'm trying to align the second-column cells. In my actual code, each cell would be a div.

[image]

I'm aware of `display:table`, unfortunately I've run into several issues using this, so I'm trying to find a flexbox solution. Ideally, I'd like the second-column cells to have different widths.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2 is longer</td>
    <td>This column is aligned either way</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my non-table HTML, that I'd like to appear identically as above. The content and width of the cells can vary as it comes from backend, but the first column should always be "as small as possible", just like an HTML table makes it with default styling.

```
<div class="lines">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="title">Column 1</div>
    <div class="description">Column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="title">Row 2 is longer</div>
    <div class="description">This column is aligned either way</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's tabular data. You could use a  table.

Comment: @Azu I've had issues styling the table, that's the reason I'm investigating flexbox alternative. Except for the alignment of the second column, I don't think design is tabular. I've understood that there are often alternatives to using tables for design nowadays.

Comment: You can use percentage values for `column` and `row` `width` and `height` to achieve a responsive result, as well. edit: @Anna yes, I believe `flexbox` to be more powerful and more flexible than old `table` displays. I personnally never use `table` in my designs and never felt the need for it.

Comment: @avia Thank you, do you have any idea how to solve this using flexbox? The cells are unfortunately of unknown width so I cannot simply specify the cell widths, as the content might grow even wider, and then I need *both* column-1 cells to expand

Comment: Please provide your non-table HTML. CSS-Grid is the obvious choice here.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for asking for clarification, I've added the non-table HTML to my question. I'll look into CSS-Grid, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ExvoQeJ

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you very much, this seems to be a perfect solution to my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current HTML you will need to use `display:contents` to "unwrap" the child containers then CSS-Grid can do the rest.

```css
.lines {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  gap: 0 1em;
}

div {
  border:1px solid grey;
}

.line {
  display:contents;
}
.title {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.description {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="lines">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="title">Column 1</div>
    <div class="description">Column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="title">Row 2 is longer</div>
    <div class="description">This column is aligned either way</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I can change the current HTML as long as the elements come in the same order, so that is not an issue.

Comment: Thank you also for introducing me to CSS Grid, which I hadn't heard of before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various `flexbox` properties to achieve this desired result, example below.

```css
.wrapper {
display:flex;
width:90vw;
margin-left:5vw;
}

.container {
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <span>Column 1</span>
    <span>Row 2 is longer</span>
    <span>Row 2 is much much longr longer much much longr longermuch much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longermuch much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longe much much longr longer much much longr longermuch much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longe</span>
    <span>I am short</span>
     <span>Row 2 is much much longr longer much much longr longermuch much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longermuch much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longe much much longr longer much much longr longermuch much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longer much much longr longe</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <span>Column 2</span>
    <span>This column is aligned either way</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you avia. The content of the first column comes from backend, so the width varies. I'm trying to get the width of the first column so that the longest cell just fits, the way it ends up in the example in my post.

Comment: OK, sure I have updated my answer. edit: Is this what you what to achieve? In any way, `flexbox` is extremely flexible and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use grid:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div>Column 1</div>
    <div>Column 2</div>
    <div>Row 2 is longer</div>
    <div>This column is aligned either way</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Azu. Here it seems that there is a large space between the two columns, I'm looking for a solution that produces no space, just like the default-styled HTML table.

Comment: You could give `.grid {width: 300px} ` or as you like.

Comment: I understand, unfortunately I do not know the width of the cells as the data comes from backend. Fortunately it seems there is a solution in the comments that works for these cases.

Answer (score 0):

The html `<table>` and its children can be used in a flex way.

I added some examples how to use the column width classes and some styling examples. Each row can have the same or a different amount of columns then the other rows. Things as `colspan` are very simple to create.

And it is responsive for smartphone, tablet and large screens.

```css
table, tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
tbody, thead, tfoot, th, td {
    display: block;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
th, td {
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: inherit;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

/* table small screen */

@media (max-width: 576px) {
    table {
        min-width: 576px;
    }
    .f-table {
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}

/* === example column width === */

th.th-25, td.td-25, .th-25 th, .td-25 td { max-width: 25%; }
th.th-33, td.td-33, .th-33 th, .td-33 td { max-width: 33.3333%; }
th.th-50, td.td-50, .th-50 th, .td-50 td { max-width: 50%; }
th.th-66, td.td-66, .th-66 th, .td-66 td { max-width: 66.6666%; }
th.th-75, td.td-75, .th-75 th, .td-75 td { max-width: 75%; }
th.th-100, td.td-100, .th-100 th, .td-100 td { max-width: 100%; }

/* === example styling === */

table {
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  border-left: 1px solid silver;
}
th, td {
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  font: normal 14px/1.3 "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 2px 5px 4px 5px;
}
th {
  background-color: #33a;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="f-table">
    <table class="td-33">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="th-33">
                <th>Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
                <th>Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
                <th>Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-66">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                <td class="td-33">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="th-100">
                <th>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi arcu ipsum.</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="td-50">
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi arcu ipsum, suscipit non placerat non.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="td-100">
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi arcu ipsum, suscipit non placerat non, egestas et diam.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```